# Curious about Fake Mails

Tags: android, email

Hi i am a little bit curious about the functionality of some android apps which are supposed to send email from any account given to them.

I just came across to fake mail send by my co-worker id. The mail was sent using one of the fake mail app. So the question arises what type of functionality they are using to create these kind of mails.

Also how to figure it out that particular mail is fake one?

Just curious to know. Is it a bug? or something else

Waiting for the answers

Comment: You can simply configure a mail server to allow for these types of messages. As far as analyzing goes. Check the headers to see where the message came from.

Comment: Point is a technical person will somehow be able to figure it out that was a fake email but how a naive person with not much technical information can figure it out?